# Null variable in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, class, null

I'm developing an iOS application and I'm having some problems when I try to save data.

My code is:

**TuplaUsuario:**

It is a class where I save user data. In that case, I use `mensaje` variable, so here is its code:

```
//TuplaUsuario.h:
@interface TuplaUsuario : NSObject
{
    NSMutableString* mensaje;
}

@property NSMutableString* mensaje;
@end    

//TuplaUsuario.m:
#import "TuplaUsuario.h"

@implementation TuplaUsuario

@synthesize mensaje;

- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)identifier {
    if ( self = [super init] ) {
        mensaje = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:identifier];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

**WebService:**

It is a class where I communicate with a Web Service.

```
//WebService.h:
#import "TuplaUsuario.h"

@interface WebService : NSObject {
    // Some other data
    NSMutableString* message;
    TuplaUsuario* usuario;
}
//Declaration of methods
@end

//WebService.m:
#import "WebService.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation WebService

- (id)init:(NSString *)identifier {
    self = [super init];
    usuario = [[TuplaUsuario alloc] initWithString:@""];
    return self;
}

- (void) processComplete: (BOOL)success {
    [[self delegate] processSuccessful:success]; 
    AppDelegate* myAppDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [myAppDelegate setUsuarioActual:usuario];
}

- (void)login:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password
{
    //Connection with Web Service
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData {
    NSDictionary* jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization
                    JSONObjectWithData:theData
                    options:0
                    error:nil];

    message = [jsonArray objectForKey:@"message"];
    [usuario setMensaje:message];
}
```

**AppDelegate:**

```
//AppDelegate.h:
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TuplaUsuario.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    Boolean rememberMe;
    TuplaUsuario* usuarioActual;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (retain) TuplaUsuario* usuarioActual;

@end

//AppDelegate.m:
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize usuarioActual;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    usuarioActual = [[TuplaUsuario alloc] initWithString:@""];

    return YES;
}
```

**PROBLEM**

In `WebService`, method `connection didReceiveData`, if I print `message` variable, it has the correct value, but if I print `[usuario mensaje]` it prints `(null)`.

Where's my error?

**SOLVED**

The problem was in my `ViewController` and `init` method of `WebService`. I called init instead of `initWithString`:

**ViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    wSProtocol = [[WebService alloc] initWithString:@""]; //Variable of type WebService
}
```

**WebService**

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)identifier {
    self = [super init];
    usuario = [[TuplaUsuario alloc] initWithString:@""];
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because this method:

```
- (id)init:(NSString *)identifier {
if ( self = [super init] ) {
    mensaje = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}
return self;
}
```

is never called, since you use:

```
usuario = [[TuplaUsuario alloc] init];
```

but is still wonder why you pass identifier into the method and never use it. I think you should make it like this:

```
mensaje = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:identifier];
```

Comment: Still not working. Now in `TuplaUsuario.m` I have `- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)identifier` and call it passing an empty string, and inside it: `mensaje = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:identifier];`

Comment: you should change synthesize mensaje; to synthesize mensaje = mensaje;

Comment: well, buddy, i'm sorry but the issue seems to have deeper origin

Comment: It was the problem, but I forgot to change `WebService init`, and in my `ViewController`.

Comment: that's great! could you please also upvote my answer since it helped? this will give me 10 points more to my reputation